# Mojo Error: package 'base64' does not contain 'b64decode'

Tags: mojolang

Using Mojo's online JupyterLab instance to run Mojo code, I am unable to decode a base64 value which I encoded using mojo itself. Here is my code

```
from base64

print(base64.b64encode("This is a "))
>>VGhpcyBpcyBhIA==
```

So far so good. Let's decode it back, now.

```
print(base64.b64decode("VGhpcyBpcyBhIA=="))
```

and here is the error message that I receive.

```
error: Expression [99]:20:17: package 'base64' does not contain 'b64decode'
    print(base64.b64decode("VGhpcyBpcyBhIA=="))
                ^

expression failed to parse (no further compiler diagnostics)
```

On their GitHub, I do see [discussion](https://github.com/modularml/mojo/issues/474) which refers to the decoding function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `b64decode` not yet implemented at the moment (2023/sept). As you can see it's missing from the documentation also: https://docs.modular.com/mojo/stdlib/base64/base64.html. The mojo project still in early stage, some functionality missing but with time it will be implemented.

In the mean time you could use python implementation instead, like this:

```py
import base64
let x = base64.b64encode("This is a ")

from python.python import Python
let base64py = Python.import_module("base64")
print(base64py.b64decode(x))
```